# ImportError: No module named lib

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open the FoxDot interface with the `python -m FoxDot` terminal command.
But I get this error:

OS: Linux

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
     mod_name, _Error)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
     __import __ (mod_name) # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
   "FoxDot / __ init__.py" file, line 120, in <module>
     from .lib import *
ImportError: No module named lib
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ludovico! I recommend you to read the help page [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More information about what are you trying to do, more possibilities to get very good answers.

Comment: You're just trying to use `FoxDot` that somebody else created? This looks like something you should [submit an issue for](https://github.com/Qirky/FoxDot/issues). It might be an issue with Python 2 support. Here is a [related but different issue](https://github.com/Qirky/FoxDot/issues/25) from before it was made compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score -2):

Have you downloaded the `lib` module? Try to download it using `pip install lib` then run it again!